# Authorize Attribute with Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I want to implement my custom authorization, I wonder what is wrong with my code even I got the user credentials correctly it still redirects me to my Login Method, please see the code below

**Edit: I have successfully implemented the Authorize Attribute with Roles, for future readers please see code below**

Login Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login (AdminViewModels.Login viewModel, string returnURL)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    PasswordHasher passwordVerify = new PasswordHasher();
    var query = (from acc in db.accounts.Where(x => x.username == viewModel.Username)
                select new { acc.username, acc.password}).FirstOrDefault();
    if (query != null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = passwordVerify.VerifyHashedPassword(query.password, viewModel.Password);
            switch (result)
            {
                case PasswordVerificationResult.Success:
//set forms ticket to be use in global.asax
                    SetupFormsAuthTicket(viewModel.Username, viewModel.rememeberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnURL);
                case PasswordVerificationResult.Failed:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong Username or Password");
                    return View(viewModel);
            }
        }
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Forms Auth Ticket

```
private account SetupFormsAuthTicket(string userName, bool persistanceFlag)
{
    account user = new account();
    var userId = user.id;
    var userData = userId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
                        userName, // user name
                        DateTime.Now,             //creation
                        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), //Expiration
                        persistanceFlag, //Persistent
                        userData);

    var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
    return user;
}
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //take out user name from cookies              
                    string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                    string[] roles = null;

                    trainingEntities db = new trainingEntities();
                    //query database to get user roles
                    var query = (from acc in db.account_roles where acc.account.username == username select acc.role.role_name).ToArray();
                    roles = query;

                    //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                      new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //somehting went wrong
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

to any action method or on top of controller

Comment: What does `return userrole.role_name;` in `ReturnUserRole()` actually return?

Comment: it should return the role of the specified username.

Comment: Curious why you have `select new {acc.account.username, acc_roles.role.role_name}` but only use the second value. And then why you have `var roles = string.Join(...)` when you only returning a single value.

Comment: i have updated my code..

Comment: That makes more sense :) Do you actually hit the `var roles = ReturnUserRole(..)` line? And what is the value of `this.UserRole`?

Comment: no it's not hitting i set a breakpoint already, the UserRole should contain a value of "Admin" @DavidG i tried placing it on the last line still not working..

Comment: In your action method, there is nowhere that actually logs the user in or does this happen in the `passwordVerify.VerifyHashedPassword` method?

Comment: i just compared the hashed password on my database to what the user inputted with that method then if it matches i will redirect them into my index controller else on unauthorized view.

Comment: But you have no code that actually sets up the authorisation, like a forms authentication cookie for example.

Comment: I think something went wring with your last edit :)

Comment: @DavidG i understand, so i need to pass the cookie to where?

Comment: @StephenMuecke what went wrong? hehe

Comment: We are now missing the auth code and have 2 sets of controller code.

Comment: Both code blocks are now the same (you deleted the `CustomAuthorization.cs` code block)

Comment: what am i missing? a form cookie?

Comment: You need to create a `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and create a cookie and add it to the response

Comment: Take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: please check my updated code i added forms authentication ticket the next step i have no idea.

Comment: i have solved this problem and posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully implemented the Authorize Attribute with Roles, for future readers please see code below.

Login Controller

```
            [HttpPost]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Login (AdminViewModels.Login viewModel, string returnURL)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(viewModel);
                }
                PasswordHasher passwordVerify = new PasswordHasher();
                var query = (from acc in db.accounts.Where(x => x.username == viewModel.Username)
                            select new { acc.username, acc.password}).FirstOrDefault();
                if (query != null)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        var result = passwordVerify.VerifyHashedPassword(query.password, viewModel.Password);
                        switch (result)
                        {
                            case PasswordVerificationResult.Success:
                               //set forms ticket to be use in global.asax
                                SetupFormsAuthTicket(viewModel.Username, viewModel.rememeberMe);
                                return RedirectToLocal(returnURL);
                            case PasswordVerificationResult.Failed:
                                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong Username or Password");
                                return View(viewModel);

                        }
                    }
                }
                return View(viewModel);

            }
```

FormsAuthTicket

```
  private account SetupFormsAuthTicket(string userName, bool persistanceFlag)
    {
        account user = new account();
        var userId = user.id;
        var userData = userId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
                            userName, // user name
                            DateTime.Now,             //creation
                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), //Expiration
                            persistanceFlag, //Persistent
                            userData);

        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
        return user;
    }
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //take out user name from cookies              
                    string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                    string[] roles = null;

                    trainingEntities db = new trainingEntities();
                    //query database to get user roles
                    var query = (from acc in db.account_roles where acc.account.username == username select acc.role.role_name).ToArray();
                    roles = query;

                    //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                      new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //somehting went wrong
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

to any action method or on top of controller

Answer (score -1):

as I see in ControllerLogin attribute it is now being applied in a variable, when it should be applied to a method or a class

```
 [CustomAuthorization(UserRole="Admin")]
 // GET: Manage
 private trainingEntities db = new trainingEntities();
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     return View();
 }


Private trainingEntities dB = new TrainingEntities();

[CustomAuthorization(UserRole="Admin")]
Public ActionResult Index()
{
   //yourcode
}
```

Comment: If it was on a variable, there would be an error message as the [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) is only allowed on class or method.